# Tag synonym `teambuild` -> `team-build` required

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

I've just noticed that someone has suggested tag wiki edits for these two tags and they are (of course) identical.

[teambuild](/questions/tagged/teambuild) has 51 questions

[team-build](/questions/tagged/team-build) has 131 questions - so I guess this should be the master.

I don't have the rep to suggest the link myself.

Comment: Retagging teambuild to team-build isn't appropriate than adding synonyms?

Comment: @YOU - not really. There are 51 posts to edit and it won't stop someone recreating `teambuild` later on. Having it as a synonym fixes both problems in one go.

Comment: Imm, there is a one shot retag function for moderators, isn't it? but I think you are right for latter case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is now a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/team-build/synonyms), and the tags have been merged into [team-build](/questions/tagged/team-build)

Comment: It's annoying that I couldn't suggest the synonym myself. I understand the limitation on having up-votes in the tags concerned but some are so obvious it would be nice if it was a 20K privilege.